# How can I get ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax of the object that is passed to the constructor?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Let's say that we have a class definition in our source code.

```
class Some
{
    private IFoo Foo { get; }

    public Some(IFoo foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }
}
```

If you open syntax visualizer, there will be only `SimpleAssignmenExpressionSyntax`. The actual object which is passed to the constructor is initialized somewhere else. `SymbolFinder.FindAllReferences` can quite help here. You can get all references to `IFoo` symbol and then check children nodes of its parent if they have `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax`. But this is valid only if you have a single instance creation of this object in the whole project. How can we find instance passed to the constructor? Seems that I need somehow to simulate execution flow.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  You can only get a syntax node from source code that actually has that syntax.

Comment: From this code you can get Syntax Node of IFoo (IdentifierNameSyntax)  which is a symbol by the way. You can get it through SemanticModel. Then you can find all references to IFoo. From ```ReferenceLocation``` object you can access ```Location.SourceSpan```. And from the SourceSpan you can get the actual SyntaxNode. i.e.  ```SyntaxTree currentSyntaxTree = location.Location.SourceTree;
            SyntaxNode referencedNode = currentSyntaxTree.GetRoot().FindNode(location.Location.SourceSpan);```

Comment: The object is initialized in the project, not outside. But, how we can find initialization of object which was passed to the constructor? Please don't blame me. I am newbie in roslyn.

Comment: So I will create visitor and will get needed nodes of object creation. And then I found that I have object instantiations in two different places. How can I check which of this two instances is passed as a parameter to the ```Some``` instance?

Comment: Ah; I misunderstood your question.  You're trying to analyze data flow, which is somewhat supported.  See https://joshvarty.com/2015/02/05/learn-roslyn-now-part-8-data-flow-analysis/

Comment: You need to receive all references for coressponding symbol of the ctor declaration `public Some(IFoo foo)` using `SymbolFinder.FindAllReferences` instead of receive references for `IFoo`. When you get all this references you should retrieve from they info about what are passed.